# Erro para atualizar os dados PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-7

Boa Tarde,

Estou tendo dificuldade para atualizar os dados,utilizando a linha de codigo abaixo.

if(isset($_POST['update'])){

```
     $id = $_POST['id_Agenda'];
     $Nome = $_POST['Nome'];
     $E_mail = $_POST['E_mail'];
     $Telefone= $_POST['Telefone'];
     $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
     $Tipo_Servico = $_POST['Tipo_Servico'];
     $Data_Horario = $_POST['Data_Horario'];

    $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Agenda SET Nome ='$Nome',E_mail ='$E_mail',Telefone ='$Telefone',sexo ='$sexo',Tipo_Servico ='$Tipo_Servico',Data_Horario ='$Data_Horario'
    WHERE id_Agenda = '$id'";
```

$result = $conexao->query($sqlUpdate);

Porem quando executo apresenta o seguinte erro
Undefined array key id_Agenda e no select do UPDATE abaixo

string(123) "UPDATE Agenda SET Nome ='',E_mail ='',Telefone ='',sexo ='',Tipo_Servico ='',Data_Horario ='' WHERE id_Agenda = ''" Record UPDATE succesfully

Comment: Importante, em vez de duplicar postagens, restaurar sua [pergunta original](/q/587210/70) e editar conforme já orientado nos comentários e quadro de fechamento. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado na postagem original, após restaurada.